# How to get number of items in a grouped row in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, count, grouping

I am finishing up my first RoR project, and am working on a leaderboard system that shows the number of points users have accrued for correctly answering quiz questions.

I am getting all of the users that have answered *at least* one question correct, grouping them by user_id, and displaying them in descending order by most correct using this:

```
@users = Point.find(:all, 
                    :group => 'user_id',
                    :order => 'correct DESC', :conditions => { :correct => "yes"})
```

In my view, I am using this to iterate through the results:

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
```

However, I am not able to get the number of correct answers per user. I tried:

```
user.count
```

but that doesn't work. How do I get the number of items per group?

Comment: What does your point model look like?  What are the attributes on it?

Comment: Point model contains point id, user_id, question_id, correct_answer, user_answer (all integers), correct (boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Seems like you would be better off using the `all` command with the count condition within it as opposed to the `count` command.  Something like this:

```
Point.all(:select => 'user_id, count(id) as point_count', :group => :user_id, :conditions => { :correct => 'yes' }, :order => 'point_count desc', :limit => 10)
```

This will return 10 limited `Point` objects with a `user_id` attribute (so you can still access the `user` relationship), and a `point_count` attribute with the number of correct points said user has obtained.

Note: you could change the limit to be however many users you wanted to display in your leaderboard.  This example would return 10.

It might make more sense to have your code look like this:

```
@points = Point.all(:select => 'user_id, count(id) as point_count', :group => :user_id, :conditions => { :correct => 'yes' }, :order => 'point_count desc', :limit => 10)
```

And as I said in a comment below, you could iterate through them by doing something like this (this would assume that your `User` model has a name attribute):

```
<table>
  <% @points.each do |point| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= point.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= point.point_count %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: had to remove the correct answer designation for a sec...it's not working 'out of the box' so I'm trying to see where the issue lies...

Comment: So what's happening is that in the controller -> :select => 'user_id, count(id) as point_count' i am getting user_id in the view but not point_count. My view looks like this: <% @users.each do | user_id, point_count| %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= user_id.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= point_count %></td>
     </tr> 
    <% end %>

Comment: I have the SQL to get what I want, now I need to translate it into ruby syntax: SELECT *, COUNT(user_id) as count FROM points WHERE correct = "yes" GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count DESC

Comment: DONE. Batkins, if you could change the sql in your query that would be great! This in the controller: @users = Point.all(:select => "*, COUNT(user_id) as count", :conditions => { :correct => 'yes' }, :group => :user_id, :order => 'count desc')

Comment: I think it is working out of the box.  You're syntax would be more like `<% @users.each do |point| %>` `<tr>` `<td>` `<%= point.user_id %>` `</td>` `<td>` `<%= point.point_count %>` `</td>` `</tr>` `<% end %>`.  You're modification to the query just makes it so that it selects every attribute on the `Point`, which seems unnecessary.  Mine just grabs the user_id and the point count, which are the only attributes you are using, right?  I think you're just accessing it improperly.

Comment: FYI you could also access the user association by calling `point.user` if your `Point` model has a `has_many :users` relationship on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you think you're getting an Array back, but you actually get a Hash back.

Try doing:

```
p @users
```

(which is equivalent to `puts @users.inspect`). You'll probably see it's more so something like:

```
{ "1" => [UserObject, UserObject], "2" => `[UserObject] }
```

You can even do `p @users.class` and you'll see it's not an array.

When you loop with a `.each_with_index` on a Hash, you need to do:

```
@users.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
```

Then you can do `@users[key].count` or `value.count`.

Comment: MrDanA: I adjusted my SQL and it seems to be working..the only thing that isn't working now is the sort by count (that's next on my list to figure out)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to get the correct count:

```
@users = Point.count(:group => :user_id, :conditions => { :correct => "yes"})
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way should be:

```
@user.points.where(:correct => "yes").count
```

Though this will only work if have defined your associations in the user and point model like

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :points

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

(personally I would have used a bool flag (smallint) instead of string for the "correct" column.

Comment: This would only work if you were examining only one user.  I agree that a boolean column would be more appropriate for storing the correct values, though.

Comment: thorsten: I successfully have the count using the comment I added below (didn't want to close the question for the benefit of others), but am struggling to do an 'order by count'